# Where are Magento 2 Remove Tags Implemented

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

Based on [this description](http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/139615758780/magento-2-10000-ft-layout-rendering-view) of Magento 2's layout rendering, where is the `remove` tag implemented in Magento?

That is, in a Magento 2 layout handle XML, you can tell Magento not to render a block with code that looks like this

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.media.image" remove="true"/>
```

It's not clear what the `remove` tag is doing.  Where is this block removed?  It it at the layout handle XML parsing stage?  The reader/scheduler stage?  The generation stage?  Somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like both the container and block reader/scheduler

```
vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Reader/Container.php
vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Reader/Block.php
```

have code that looks something like this

```
    $containerRemove = filter_var($currentElement->getAttribute('remove'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);

    if ($containerRemove) {
        $scheduledStructure->setElementToRemoveList($containerName);
    } else {
        $this->mergeContainerAttributes($scheduledStructure, $currentElement);
    }
```

i.e., the readers look for references with remove blocks, and then schedule the remove.

The block itself is actually removed when the `GeneratorPool` does the initial build out of the layout structure

```
#File: vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php
foreach ($scheduledStructure->getListToRemove() as $elementToRemove) {
    $this->removeElement($scheduledStructure, $structure, $elementToRemove);
}
```